# apply css on elements which are present in a set of urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I believe the following is not possible without javascript/jquery but still wanted to confirm as I am not good in css/html/jquery.

I would like to apply certain style to an element but only when a particular url is accessed in my website.

I am using asp.net so a single aspx page template can cater to a host of urls so I cannot write the style in the html of the template.

If I write this style in a css file and include it in the template it will get applied to all urls.

I can selectively load this css file through jquery but I do not want to involve jquery into this as much as possible.

I can also use a `asp.net literal control` and load the css based on the url from code-behind but then addition of new urls would involve a code change. Also it sounds very messy.

Currently I am applying this through javascript/jquery as below on `document.ready`

```
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("/some-url/") > 0)
{
    $('#some-element-id').attr('style', 'display:none');
}
```

But this shows the element for a split of a second before disappearing.

A solution involving jquery/javascript but resolving the above issue will also help.

I hope I was able to explain it properly.

Please let me know if any clarification is required.

Comment: I would load the stylesheet based on the URL. A .net or php code to check the url and apply the css accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably showing at first because it is rendered at least a bit before the page is loaded, so it is shown until the jQuery `ready()` function is called on page load.

I would think the easiest fix would be to hide the element by default, then show it if it *is* in the URL:

```
#some-element-id{
    display:none;
}
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("/some-url/") < 0)
{
    $('#some-element-id').attr('style', 'display:block');
}
```

Comment: Hi jacob, It would be one and the same thing just the other way around. It will stop the flickering though

Comment: @samar yes, but it wouldn't show briefly at page load

Answer (score 0):

if `#some-element-id` is on a separate page then

1. add `some-class` to your element
2. define that class in a new .css file
3. only import that new .css file on the page you want the style
   applied to

Answer (score 0):

The `URL` is not part of the `DOM` so there’s no element to be selected by the `CSS`.

As you say the only way you can apply the css in a specific `URL` is using javascript.

The recommendation I can tell you is use `addClass` instead to use

`.attr('style', 'display:none');`

Or if you need to add a lot of css you also can include or replace the a full file like:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="youStilefile.css" type="text/css" />');
```

I hope it's helps!

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is separate your css styles by codes that generated from server (independent from client).

Also you can test below code instead of `$('#some-element-id').attr('style', 'display:block');`

```
$('#some-element-id').hide();
```

and please insure that your jq lib imported successfully.